# C - "Argument type 'void' is incomplete" error using a function to print trees

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function which allows trees of different sizes to be printed when calling from the main function. Unfortunately when I run my code I get the error "Argument type 'void' is incomplete" three times in my main function. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tree(int rows)
{
int i, j;

for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
{
    for(j=i; j<rows; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(j=1; j<=(2*i-1); j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
 }

int main()
{
    int rows;
    rows = 5;
    printf("%d\n", tree(rows));
    rows = 3;
    printf("%d\n", tree(rows));
    rows = 6;
    printf("%d\n", tree(rows));
}
```

I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: your printf expects a return type of **int**, however, tree returns **void**.

Comment: So I need to change %d?

Comment: What information should the `printf` in `main` show?

Comment: I don't know why you're calling the printf's in main, But could just invoke **tree** by calling it directly inside main.

Comment: Yup I see what I was doing now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change your `tree` function you could simply call tree (without being called inside `printf`).
As pointed out by T. Obadiah, the `printf` statement expects an `int`, but your function is `void`.
Your implementation of `tree` already prints the output.

```
void tree(int rows)
{
int i, j;

for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
{
    for(j=i; j<rows; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(j=1; j<=(2*i-1); j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
 }

int main()
{
    int rows;
    rows = 5;
    tree(rows);
    rows = 3;
    tree(rows);
    rows = 6;
    tree(rows);
}
```

Output for `rows = 5`:

```
    *                                                                                                                                                               
   ***                                                                                                                                                              
  *****                                                                                                                                                             
 *******                                                                                                                                                            
*********
```

Comment: @Rachel you're welcome. As a new member you may also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I'll check it out!